# Volume by disk perpendicular to $x$ axis

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, applications

Find the volume of the solid formed when region enclosed by $y=x^{1/2},\quad y=6-x$ and $y=0$ revolves around $x$ axis.

Can I use the equation for finding solids by splitting the solid into 2 parts?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa6ki.jpg)

Comment: In StackMath here, you may use $\LaTeX$ to make your idea attractive to viewers.

Comment: Yes for disk method, split it into two. Use the equations to find intersection of curves and the limits of both integral.

Comment: Please edit showing your attempt if you get stuck and need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=x^{1/2},\quad y=6-x$  , so put $x^{1/2} =6-x$

square both sides and get to $x^2 -13x +36 =0$

solutions are 4 and 9, use $x=4$ and $x=0$  for the limits in the volume formula $V=\int \pi y^2 dx$ for curve $y=x^{1/2}$.

Then similar for the line equation, between 4 and 6. Do separately then add.

Draw a diagram to see the $x=6$ point and why $x=4$ was used, not $x=9$.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate area from known shapes

$$ 4\cdot2\cdot\dfrac23+2\cdot 2\cdot\dfrac12 $$